# Loop List<WebElement> doesn't stop despite no more WebElements

Tags: java, selenium, for-loop, arraylist

I want to click on these three different webelements in this sequence `showmorebutton, viewrepliesbutton, readmorebutton` on a youtube comments page (for eg. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VtTRcWXSBwc).

Below is the code I have written.

```
//iterate through the comments 
//for(int j=0; j <= commententry.size(); j++){
for (WebElement comment : commententry) {
    boolean clickMore = true;

    try {
        while(clickMore == true) {
            //int counting = 0;
            //if (counting == j){
                //find web elements by class name                       
                List<WebElement> viewrepliesbutton  = comment.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='show-more']//span[@class='sprite_caret down']")); //view replies
                List<WebElement> readmorebutton = comment.findElements(By.className("comment-text-toggle")); //read more
                List<WebElement> showmorebutton =  dr.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'yt-comments-paginator')]")); //show more

                try{
                    //click more comments
                    if(showmorebutton.size() > 0) {
                        for (WebElement showmore_element : showmorebutton ) {                                                      
                            Utility.click(showmore_element); //click on button if found
                            System.out.println("show more ");
                            Thread.sleep(3000); //pause for 5 seconds                      
                        }
                    } else clickMore = false; 

                    for (WebElement viewreplies_element : viewrepliesbutton ) {                                           
                                Utility.click(viewreplies_element); //click on button if found
                                System.out.println("view replies");
                                Thread.sleep(3000); //pause for 5 seconds                     
                    } 

                    for (WebElement readmore_element : readmorebutton){    
                        Utility.click(readmore_element); //click on button if found
                        System.out.println("read more");
                        Thread.sleep(3000); //pause for 5 seconds
                    }

                //j++;
                } catch(Exception e){
                    Logger.getLogger(ExpandYoutube.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Oops, something happened!", e);
                }
            //} else break;  
        }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) { //when no elements are found
        Logger.getLogger(ExpandYoutube.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Oops, something happened!", e);
    }      
}
```

**Issue:** the loop still continues even when there are no more webelements on the page, have added `else break;` , `else clickMore = false;` to stop the loop but failed.

**Output** In this case, should have stopped at the second time of the loop but carried on to the third and fourth one.

```
    run:
    .
    Page Loaded.
    Pausing for 5 seconds:  1 2 3 4 5
    [[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (279f52ea-c071-45c9-96d4-6339a22d5a51)] -> xpath: //div[@class='comment-replies-header']], [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (279f52ea-c071-45c9-96d4-6339a22d5a51)] -> xpath: //div[@class='comment-replies-header']], [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (279f52ea-c071-45c9-96d4-6339a22d5a51)] -> xpath: //div[@class='comment-replies-header']], [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (279f52ea-c071-45c9-96d4-6339a22d5a51)] -> xpath: //div[@class='comment-replies-header']], [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (279f52ea-c071-45c9-96d4-6339a22d5a51)] -> xpath: //div[@class='comment-replies-header']], [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (279f52ea-c071-45c9-96d4-6339a22d5a51)] -> xpath: //div[@class='comment-replies-header']]]
    show more 
    view replies
    view replies
    view replies
    view replies
    view replies
    view replies
    show more 
    view replies
    view replies
    view replies
    view replies
    view replies
    view replies
    view replies
    view replies
    view replies
    view replies
    show more 
    view replies
    view replies
    view replies
    view replies
    view replies
    view replies
    view replies
    view replies
    BUILD STOPPED (total time: 4 minutes 12 seconds)
```

Comment: your logic seems not complete, do you want to display everthing? if so the first loop is not need and  there is just one `showmorebutton`. therefore iterate until `showmorebutton` viewable and inside this click  `viewrepliesbutton`.

Comment: yes, i want to display everything. however, after the first `showmorebutton`, there is another one. @MesutGüneş

Comment: yes it is the same button, you just need to click it and do your staff until it is on the page.

Comment: please see my edit above. what im trying to do is to click `showmorebutton` on the page if available, followed by `viewrepliesbutton` then`readmorebutton` like what you have mentioned but am i doing it wrongly as shown in the codes and output? @MesutGüneş

Comment: result seems ok. What is missing?

Comment: `readmorebutton` is not clicked at all and the result should have stopped at the second show more but instead, it went passed and carried on looping despite there are no more elements after the second one. @MesutGüneş

Comment: @newbie-224466 see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate until `showmorebutton` is visible, inside the loop click `readmorebutton` and `viewrepliesbutton`. See the code below to give an idea:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("yt-comments-list")));

try {
    while (dr.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='yt-comments-paginator']")).size() > 0) {
        System.out.println("show more ");
        dr.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='yt-comments-paginator']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000); //pause for 5 seconds
    }
} catch(Exception e){
    Logger.getLogger(ExpandYoutube.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Oops, something happened!", e);
}

List<WebElement> readmorebutton = dr.findElements(By.className("comment-text-toggle")); 
List<WebElement> viewrepliesbutton = dr.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='show-more']//span[@class='sprite_caret down']")); 

for (WebElement viewreplies_element : viewrepliesbutton ) {                                           
    Utility.click(viewreplies_element); //click on button if found
    System.out.println("view replies");
    Thread.sleep(3000); //pause for 5 seconds                     
} 

for (WebElement readmore_element : readmorebutton){    
    Utility.click(readmore_element); //click on button if found
    System.out.println("read more");
    Thread.sleep(3000); //pause for 5 seconds
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to resolve **incompatible types: WebElement cannot be converted to boolean** for `while(showmorebutton)`? Also, if there isn't any `showmorebutton` in the page, will the `readmorebutton` and `viewrepliesbutton` be still clicked?

Comment: @newbie_224466 `findElements' returns a list if no element found it returns empty list. We can use it here. If there is not 'showmorebutton' no need to click others.

Comment: but i want is that even if there is no `showmorebutton`, the others will still be clicked if they are on the page. @Mesut

Comment: @newbie_224466 It does what you want. Check it. I meant no need to run click.

Comment: what i meant is that for your codes, if `dr.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='yt-comments-paginator']")` is > 0, it will enter the loop and click all the elements if available. but if there is no `yt-comments-paginator`, it will not enter the loop and click on others. what i want is to click on others even if there is no `yt-comments-paginator` @Mesut

Comment: @newbie_224466 it is not a case in this url but for generic solution I updated the code.

Comment: the updated codes works fine for page that has no `yt-comments-paginator`. however, now it wont click on `viewrepliesbutton` and `readmorebutton` that are supposedly on the second page

Comment: @newbie_224466 Final update. You could also solve this :)

Answer (score 0):

you are iterating on commententry list twice. once using `for(int j=0; j <= commententry.size(); j++)`
and another using:

```
for (WebElement comment : commententry)
```

so what is happening is even though you are breaking out of inner foreach loop but your outer for loop is still running. which is why the inner loop starts all over again. what you need to do is use only one `for loop`

Comment: i tried using either one of the loops only and the results are still the same @mrunal